# Why do DQNs tend to forget?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, experience-replay, catastrophic-forgetting

Why do DQNs tend to forget? Is it because when you feed highly correlated samples, your model (function approximation) doesn't give a general solution?

For example:

- I use level 1 experiences, my model $p$ is fitted to learn how to play that level.
- I go to level 2, my weights are updated and fitted to play level 2 meaning I don't know how to play level 1 again.

Comment: Please, do not ask the same question in different posts only because you have not yet received an answer. You already asked about ER here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22694/2444. I am sure someone will answer that question.

Comment: This question is very related to https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13289/2444, although I wouldn't say it's a duplicate because yours is specific to DQN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referring to catastrophic forgetting which could be an issue in any neural net. More specifically for DQN refer to this [article](https://www.pnas.org/content/114/13/3521).

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, Thank you

Comment: I also have a question, the issue is our replay memory size can’t be too large because of performance issues, too small and it’s irrelevant, so if we have a large space state with multiple tasks, even replay memory wouldn’t be able to help with the catastrophic forgetting, so what can be the solution?

Comment: @Chukwudi I'm not really sure, sorry.